# Why am I getting the original word plus the reverse word?

Tags: java, for-loop, append, stringbuilder, charat

My return for the input "no" is showing up as "noon"
I'm seeing where it is adding the original word to the `StringBuilder`. How do I get it to not do that, and only add the characters to an empty `StringBuilder`, in reverse?

```java
public class Palindrome
{
    public static String reversed(String originalWord)
    {
        int lengthOfWord = originalWord.length();
        StringBuilder reversedWordBuilder = new StringBuilder(originalWord);

        for (int currentChar = lengthOfWord-1; currentChar >= 0; currentChar--)
        {
            reversedWordBuilder.append(Character.toString(originalWord.charAt(currentChar)));
        }
        
        return reversedWordBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are initializing the [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#StringBuilder(java.lang.CharSequence)) with the originalWord itself:

```
StringBuilder reversedWordBuilder = new StringBuilder(originalWord);
```

so it already have initial a value of "no", then you append the reversed one to it. You should initialize it with empty constructor like:

```
StringBuilder reversedWordBuilder = new StringBuilder();
```

and then to do your logic in the loop.

Since you already use StringBuilder you can do in one liner as it follows:

```
public static String reversed(String originalWord) {

    return new StringBuilder(originalWord).reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: You can also use a `StringBuffer` to reverse it. Might be better practice.